# No Overload for txtCash_KeyUp matches the delegate 'KeyEventHandler'

Tags: c#, winforms

my textbox:

```
private void txtCash_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs f, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
                                                         //need to add this for getting row counts
    {
        if (f.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
         
                for(int i = 0; i < fpos.dgSales.Rows.Count;i++)
                {
                    Products prod = new Products
                    {
                        ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(fpos.dgSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString()),
                        ProductCode = fpos.dgSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(fpos.dgSales.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString()),
                    };
                    prod.Product_UpdateQtySales();
                }
            
        }
    }
```

I added`DataGridViewCellEventArgs e` to add this to get row counts. but i got an error on the designer of this form.

> error line // this.txtCash.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.txtCash_KeyUp);
> Error // No Overload for txtCash_KeyUp matches the delegate 'KeyEventHandler'

Comment: Is it the *row count* or rather the *row number* you want? I'd expect you should be able to retrieve either by inspecting `sender`. The error simply tells you you cannot expect DataGridViewCellEventArgs being passed to a KeyEventHandler just because you put it in your handler implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `KeyEventHandler` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventhandler) has the following signature:

```cs
void KeyEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e);
```

The method `txtCash_KeyUp` has this signature:

```cs
void txtCash_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs f, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e);
```

To convert a method group to a delegate type (which is what you are trying to do with `new KeyEventHandler(this.txtCash_KeyUp)`), the signatures have to be compatible, but since you added an additional parameter, this is not the case anymore.

The code calling that event handler has no idea you want those `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` or where to get them. You will have to retrieve that information in a different way.